# Flutter - UI is not updated correctly when removing an element

Tags: list, dart, flutter

I'm trying to build a page in which users can add and remove elements from a list.
I'm struggling with a problem. When I remove an element, the model is updated correctly while the UI is updated but in a wrong way: only the last element of the list is removed.

I'm using Flutter 1.5.4.

I already using simpler elements for the list and I tried to build a new project with only this page to remove all possible problems, but it still doesn't work correctly.

I also tried using a Column instead of a List but the result is always the same.

main.dart:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './widget.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hello'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: SectionWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

widget.dart:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SectionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  _SectionWidgetState createState() => new _SectionWidgetState();
}

class _SectionWidgetState extends State<SectionWidget> {
  List<String> _items = List<String>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> children = [
      ListTile(
          title: Text(
            "Strings",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _items.add('item ${_items.length}');
                  print("Adding "+ _items.last);
                }),
          ),
        ),
    ];

    children.addAll(_buildForms());


    return ListView(
      children: children,
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildForms() {
    List<Widget> forms = new List<Widget>();
    print("Strings:" + _items.toString());
    for (String item in _items) {
      forms.add(
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.person),
          title: TextFormField(
            initialValue: item,
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  print("Removing $item");
                  _items.remove(item);
                }),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return forms;
  }
}
```

If I add 4 items to the list and then remove "item 1", this is the output on the console:

```
I/flutter ( 4192): Strings:[]
I/flutter ( 4192): Adding item 0
I/flutter ( 4192): Strings:[item 0]
I/flutter ( 4192): Adding item 1
I/flutter ( 4192): Strings:[item 0, item 1]
I/flutter ( 4192): Adding item 2
I/flutter ( 4192): Strings:[item 0, item 1, item 2]
I/flutter ( 4192): Adding item 3
I/flutter ( 4192): Strings:[item 0, item 1, item 2, item 3]
I/flutter ( 4192): Removing item 1
I/flutter ( 4192): Strings:[item 0, item 2, item 3]
```

Which is correct, as "item 1" was removed from the list, but if I look at the UI, this is what i get:

[image]

The number of elements in the list is correct, the model is correct, but the elements shown are wrong.

How do I fix this? Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug of Flutter?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you can do is pass to the `ListView` the `Key` which will contain the length of the elements in the list.

```dart
ListView(
  key: Key(myList.length.toString()),
  children: myList.map(...),
),
```

**Why it works?**
It causes the whole `ListView` to rebuild itself from scratch but only when the length on your list changes. What's important is that it doesn't happen in other cases (like typing inside a TextField) because such action would cause you to lose focus on every letter type.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: After wasting my full day I came to this answer. Thanks @Marcin.

Comment: For Christ. This should be baked into the framework. Banging my head for hours. Thanks.

Comment: Ahhh I need to add the key to the listbuilder and not the childs. That helped. Was facing an issue where I've added ['a', 'b', ''] in the list. Then removed 'a' the the ui looked like ['', 'b'] even though my data looked like ['b', ''].. Thanks Marcin ❤️

Comment: What a life saver. I was stuck on this for 8 hours and all the code I wrote performed as expected. I was losing it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

**This is not a solution but an explanation, refer to Marcin Szałek's comment for the solution.**

The **reason** that the `ListView` does not rerender as expected is that the `TextFormField` is a stateful widget. When you rebuild the widgets, you need to take note that there are 3 trees under the hood, which are the Widget, Element and RenderObject tree. The RenderObject is the visual representation, and is directly based on the Element. Whereas the Element is directly based on the Widget, and the Widget is just the configuration, i.e. what you type in code.

When first instantiating a widget, a corresponding element is created. However, when you call `setState()` to change the _items list, the widget is rebuild, but the element is not destroyed and recreated. Rather, **in order to maximise efficiency**, Flutter is made such that it first compares any differences between the initial `ListTile` widgets and the rebuild `ListTile` widgets. In this case, initially there are 4 tiles, and afterwards there are 3 tiles. Instead of recreating new tiles, the elements of the second and third tiles are updated to have the attributes of the rebuild `ListTile` widgets (and no changes occur for the first tile because the widget/configuration before and after is the same). The 4th element is popped from the Element tree. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996ZgFRENMs) by the official Flutter team does a great job at explaining the three trees.

Using Dart's Devtools, you can find no change in the key/id of the third element. When you inspect the third `ListTile`, before and after the key is *#3dded*.

---

**Initial**

[image: Phone]
[image: Initially]

**After deletion**

[image: Phone]
[image: Finally]

To remove the elements from the tree and then put them back in, attach a key to the `ListView` as commented by Marcin Szałek. For stateful widgets, elements will be updated when the corresponding new widget is of the same widget type and has the same key. Without explicitly specifying the key, the element will only check whether it is of the same type as the corresponding widget, and as all the widgets are of runtime type `ListTile`, then there would not be any update of the elements, thus you see item 0 and item 1 instead of item 0 and item 2. I recommend that you read more about keys [here](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d).

Using Dart's Devtools, you can find the change in the key of the third `ListTile`. Initially, when it was item 1, the key was *#5addd*. Then, when item 1 is deleted, the key changes to *#26044*.

---

**Initial**

[image: Phone]
[image: Initially]

**After deletion**

[image: Phone]
[image: Finally]

Answer (score 2):

The reason for removing not updating the deleted element is the second widget is stateful widget it needs force rendering in some case

use this code to get reload the view by overriding the didUpdateWidget method

```
 @override
  void didUpdateWidget(LoadImageFromPathAsync oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget != widget) {
        setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem as the guy who asked the question, I'm trying to use the didUpdateWidget with the code that the guy provided, but I cannot achieve any good result.  Using the code that the guy provided, can you tell me where do I have to call didUpdateWidget and what widget do I have to pass? Thankyou

Comment: Just place the didUpdateWidget in statefulwidget as like initState you will get the result, or paste the code here or link to view your code so that it will be helpful to sort out the issue.

Comment: this worked like charm, I have too many filed so assigning key to each filed was a hassle but this solution is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I tried Marcin Szałek Solution but I'm using BLoC to rebuild the widget so his solution caused an issue as follow:

1- add first element (TextField) to the list and type "a" in it

2- add second element (TextField) to the list (boom the first TextField will become empty)

I don't actually know if this will happen when we are not using the BLoC.
But if you are using BLoC try this solution it worked for me like a charm:

1- create list of `UniqueKey`

```
List<UniqueKey> listKeys = [];
```

2- when you click on the add icon to add an element to the `ListView` make sure to add object of `UniqueKey` to the `listKeys`

```
listKeys.add(UniqueKey());
```

3- attach each `listKeys` list members to the `ListView` items

```
ListView.builder(
   shrinkWrap: true,
   itemCount: items?.length ?? 0,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         return ListItem(
            key: listKeys[index];
      );
    },
   )
```

4- when you remove element "TextField" form the `ListView` you must delete it form the `listKyes` to

```
listKeys.removeAt(deleteIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you need to create controllers for every textfield or use hintText

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Strings',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      _items.add('item ${_items.length}');
                      print('Adding '+ _items.last);
                    }),
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: _items.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i){
                return ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                  title: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: _items[i]
                    ),
                  ),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onPressed: () => setState(() {
                          print('Removing ${_items[i]}');
                          _items.remove(_items[i]);
                        }),
                  ),
                );
              },
            )
          ]
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your widget state only holds the list of Strings. When you remove one of them and the widget is rebuilt, Flutter knows that your `ListView` contains one less child widget, so it removes the last one and rebuilds the other ones.

The catch here is that you're using `initialValue` to set the text on the `TextFormFields` - the whole point of `initialValue` is that it won't change the text on the field even if you change it - a `TextFormField` can only have 1 initial value and that's the one you're setting initially.

If you want the text to change, you need to use a `TextEditingController`. In your example above, simply replacing `initialValue: item` with `controller: TextEditingController(text: item)` should fix it. In a real application you'd likely want to store the controllers in the state of the widget though, so that the user-entered values are persisted across rebuilds.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, `setState` function only update widget data not re-create widget. In your code, you use initialValue to set default text for `TextField`. This param is only used when `TextField` is created. So when you remove an item, app will update widget depends on `_item`'s length (in this case, keep 3 first one and remove the last one). `initialValue` is no meaning at this time because `TextField` is not created but reused.

To solve this, you can use [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) to set text instead of `initialVal`

First, create a list of `TextEditingController` map with `_items`

```
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];
```

Then, when add an item also create a new controller for it

```
onPressed: () => setState(() {
  _items.add('item ${_items.length}');
  controllers.add(TextEditingController(text:  "${_items.length}"));
  print("Adding "+ _items.last);
}),
```

Finally, add controller to `TextField`

```
TextFormField(
  controller: controllers[_items.indexOf(item)],
)
```

Ah, don't forget to remove controller before remove item

```
controllers.removeAt(_items.indexOf(item));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use key or controller fields for TextFormField elements.

```
TextFormField(
    key: GlobalKey(),
    ....
)
```

Comment: this solution is not good because in some cases the keyboard will disappear immediately when you click on the text field to open it