# Deleting item from Flutters ListView removes the last widget only

Tags: listview, flutter

I have a `ListView` that contains `StateFull Widgets`, each of these `Tiles` represents one object from a list. The problem is that when I try to delete objects from that list, only the last `Tile` will be removed on the screen. For deleting items I use a reference to the appropriate method (`_deleteItem(_HomeItem item)`) to each `Tile`. I suspect this is a problem with the `Keys` I use, but I am not sure. I already tried to use different keys (i.e. `ObjectKey(item)` and `GlobalKey<_TileState>()`) instead, but that did not change anything.

I found only one question regarding my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271621/flutter-ui-is-not-updated-correctly-when-removing-an-element). But the solutions there either do not work, or I followed them incorrectly.

This is a minimal working example for what I try to do:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Slidable Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Slidable Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<_HomeItem> items = List.generate(
    5,
    (i) => _HomeItem(
      i,
      'Tile n°$i',
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _buildList(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Tile(items[index], _deleteItem);
      },
      itemCount: items.length,
    );
  }

  void _deleteItem(_HomeItem item) {
    setState(() {
      print(context);
      print("remove: $item");
      print("Number of items before: ${items.length}");
      items.remove(item);
      print("Number of items after delete: ${items.length}");
    });
  }
}

class Tile extends StatefulWidget {
  final _HomeItem item;
  final Function delete;

  Tile(this.item, this.delete);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TileState(item, delete);
}

class _TileState extends State<Tile> {
  final _HomeItem item;
  final Function delete;

  _TileState(this.item, this.delete);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      key: ValueKey(item.index),
      title: Text("${item.title}"),
      subtitle: Text("${item.index}"),
      onTap: () => delete(item),
    );
  }
}

class _HomeItem {
  const _HomeItem(
    this.index,
    this.title,
  );

  final int index;
  final String title;
}
```

Because this lead to misunderstandings, here is what each item in the list is right now:

```
/*
  privacyIDEA Authenticator

  Authors: Timo Sturm <timo.sturm@netknights.it>

  Copyright (c) 2017-2019 NetKnights GmbH

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
*/

import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:privacyidea_authenticator/model/tokens.dart';
import 'package:privacyidea_authenticator/utils/storageUtils.dart';
import 'package:privacyidea_authenticator/utils/util.dart';

class TokenWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Token _token;
  final Function _delete;

  TokenWidget(this._token, this._delete);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    if (_token is HOTPToken) {
      return _HotpWidgetState(_token, _delete);
    } else if (_token is TOTPToken) {
      return _TotpWidgetState(_token, _delete);
    } else {
      throw ArgumentError.value(_token, "token",
          "The token [$_token] is of unknown type and not supported.");
    }
  }
}

abstract class _TokenWidgetState extends State<TokenWidget> {
  final Token _token;
  static final SlidableController _slidableController = SlidableController();
  String _otpValue;
  String _label;

  final Function _delete;

  _TokenWidgetState(this._token, this._delete) {
    _otpValue = calculateOtpValue(_token);
    _saveThisToken();
    _label = _token.label;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slidable(
      key: ValueKey(_token.serial),
      // This is used to only let one Slidable be open at a time.
      controller: _slidableController,
      actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
      actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: _buildTile(),
      ),
      secondaryActions: <Widget>[
        IconSlideAction(
          caption: 'Delete',
          color: Colors.red,
          icon: Icons.delete,
          onTap: () => _deleteTokenDialog(),
        ),
        IconSlideAction(
          caption: 'Rename',
          color: Colors.blue,
          icon: Icons.edit,
          onTap: () => _renameTokenDialog(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  // TODO Test this behaviour with integration testing.
  void _renameTokenDialog() {
    final _nameInputKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
    String _selectedName;

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Rename token"),
            titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
            content: TextFormField(
              autofocus: true,
              initialValue: _label,
              key: _nameInputKey,
              onChanged: (value) => this.setState(() => _selectedName = value),
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Name"),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter a name for this token.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Rename"),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_nameInputKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    _renameToken(_selectedName);
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Cancel"),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  void _renameToken(String newLabel) {
    _saveThisToken();
    log(
      "Renamed token:",
      name: "token_widgets.dart",
      error: "\"${_token.label}\" changed to \"$newLabel\"",
    );
    _token.label = newLabel;

    setState(() {
      _label = _token.label;
    });
  }

  void _deleteTokenDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Confirm deletion"),
            titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
            content: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "Are you sure you want to delete ",
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                        text: "\'$_label\'?",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        ))
                  ]),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => {
                  _delete(_token),
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                },
                child: Text("Yes!"),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                child: Text("No, take me back!"),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  void _saveThisToken() {
    StorageUtil.saveOrReplaceToken(this._token);
  }

  void _updateOtpValue();

  Widget _buildTile();
}

class _HotpWidgetState extends _TokenWidgetState {
  _HotpWidgetState(Token token, Function delete) : super(token, delete);

  @override
  void _updateOtpValue() {
    setState(() {
      (_token as HOTPToken).incrementCounter();
      _otpValue = calculateOtpValue(_token);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget _buildTile() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          title: Center(
            child: Text(
              insertCharAt(_otpValue, " ", _otpValue.length ~/ 2),
              textScaleFactor: 2.5,
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: Center(
            child: Text(
              _label,
              textScaleFactor: 2.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => _updateOtpValue(),
            child: Text(
              "Next",
              textScaleFactor: 1.5,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _TotpWidgetState extends _TokenWidgetState
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController
      controller; // Controller for animating the LinearProgressAnimator

  _TotpWidgetState(Token token, Function delete) : super(token, delete);

  @override
  void _updateOtpValue() {
    setState(() {
      _otpValue = calculateOtpValue(_token);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(seconds: (_token as TOTPToken).period),
      // Animate the progress for the duration of the tokens period.
      vsync:
          this, // By extending SingleTickerProviderStateMixin we can use this object as vsync, this prevents offscreen animations.
    )
      ..addListener(() {
        // Adding a listener to update the view for the animation steps.
        setState(() => {
              // The state that has changed here is the animation object’s value.
            });
      })
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        // Add listener to restart the animation after the period, also updates the otp value.
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          controller.forward(from: 0.0);
          _updateOtpValue();
        }
      })
      ..forward(); // Start the animation.

    // Update the otp value when the android app resumes, this prevents outdated otp values
    // ignore: missing_return
    SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg) {
      log(
        "SystemChannels:",
        name: "totpwidget.dart",
        error: msg,
      );
      if (msg == AppLifecycleState.resumed.toString()) {
        _updateOtpValue();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose(); // Dispose the controller to prevent memory leak.
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget _buildTile() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          title: Center(
            child: Text(
              insertCharAt(_otpValue, " ", _otpValue.length ~/ 2),
              textScaleFactor: 2.5,
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: Center(
            child: Text(
              _label,
              textScaleFactor: 2.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        LinearProgressIndicator(
          value: controller.value,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The plan is to add different kind of items to the list in the future, each of that will probably be presented completely different, and also require different logic. For the full project please refer to [github](https://github.com/privacyidea/pi-authenticator/tree/delete_and_rename_tokens). While I am convinced that this is the right way to create different Widgets for the list, I am open for different approaches to do this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should set `Key` for each Tile. You can watch this [Flutter Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc) to understand what is going on in your code.

I used `ObjectKey` in the following code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Slidable Demo',
      home: MyListPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyListPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyListPageState createState() => _MyListPageState();
}

class _MyListPageState extends State<MyListPage> {
  final List<Item> items = [
    Item("ItemName_1", "ItemType_1"),
    Item("ItemName_2", "ItemType_2"),
    Item("ItemName_3", "ItemType_1"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Flutter Slidable Demo"),
      ),
      body: _buildList(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final item = items[index];
        return MyTile(
          key: ObjectKey(item),
          item: items[index],
          onDeleteClicked: () => _deleteItem(item),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _deleteItem(Item item) {
    items.remove(item);
    setState(() {});
  }
}

class Item {
  String itemName;
  String itemType;

  Item(this.itemName, this.itemType);
}

class MyTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Item item;
  final VoidCallback onDeleteClicked;

  const MyTile({Key key, this.item, this.onDeleteClicked}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyTileState createState() {
    if (item.itemType == "ItemType_1")
      return TileStateType1();
    else if (item.itemType == "ItemType_2")
      return TileStateType2();
    else
      throw ArgumentError.value("Unknown Item type and not supported.");
  }
}

abstract class _MyTileState extends State<MyTile> {
  void _renameItem() {
    final txtCtrl = TextEditingController(text: widget.item.itemName);
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Rename"),
          content: TextField(
            controller: txtCtrl,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text("Confirm", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  widget.item.itemName = txtCtrl.text;
                });
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text("Cancel", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _deleteItem() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Delete"),
            content: Text("Are you sure?"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text("Confirm", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                onPressed: () {
                  widget.onDeleteClicked();
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text("Cancel", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 3.0,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: _doDifferently,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: _buildDifferently(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: _renameItem,
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: _deleteItem,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDifferently();

  void _doDifferently();
}

class TileStateType1 extends _MyTileState {
  @override
  Widget _buildDifferently() {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          widget.item.itemName,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Material(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Text(
              widget.item.itemType,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void _doDifferently() {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("I am type 1"),
    ));
  }
}

class TileStateType2 extends _MyTileState {
  @override
  Widget _buildDifferently() {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.security),
        Text(
          widget.item.itemName,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
        ),
        Material(
          color: Colors.red,
          shape: StadiumBorder(),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Text(
              widget.item.itemType,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void _doDifferently() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Message"),
            content: Text("I am type 2"),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution was indeed, to provide a `Key` for each Tile in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Slidable Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Slidable Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<_HomeItem> items = List.generate(
    5,
    (i) => _HomeItem(
      i,
      'Tile n°$i',
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _buildList(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        _HomeItem item = items[i];
          return ListTile(

            title: Text(item.index.toString()),
            subtitle: Text(item.title.toString()),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                items.removeAt(i);
              });
            },

          );
      },
      itemCount: items.length,
    );
  }
}



class _HomeItem {
  const _HomeItem(
    this.index,
    this.title,
  );

  final int index;
  final String title;
}
```

Other solution: -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Slidable Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Slidable Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   List<_HomeItem> items = [];

   @override
  void initState() {
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      items.add(_HomeItem(i, 'Title $i', Key(i.toString())));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _buildList(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return tiles(items[index], _deleteItem);
      },
      itemCount: items.length,
    );
  }

  Widget tiles(_HomeItem item, Function detete) {
    return ListTile(
            key: item.key,
            title: Text("${item.title}"),
            subtitle: Text("${item.index}"),
            onTap: () => detete(item),
      );
  } 
    void _deleteItem(_HomeItem itemtoDelete,) {
    for(int i =0; i <items.length; i++) {
        if(items[i].key == itemtoDelete.key) {
          setState(() {
            items.removeWhere((item) => item.key == itemtoDelete.key);
          });
        }else {
        }
    }
    }
  }

class _HomeItem {
  const _HomeItem(
    this.index,
    this.title,
    this.key,
  );

  final int index;
  final String title;
   final Key key;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is indeed a possible solution. But it would force me to move all my logic to the `_MyHomePageState` class. As the list will have to present at least three different subclasses of `_HomeItem`, each with different logic and visual representation, this is not the way I want to go if I can prevent it.

Comment: An explanation on why this is a solution would be nice.

@OnkelZukunft, your list will only be rebuild by Flutter if you use `setState` when changing the list.

You do not have to move all your logic there, but you have to call `setState` and set a new list there.

Comment: I have updated my answer added an alternative solve.

Comment: Your Tile() class is just rendring the UI so what business logic you are expecting to run there? Other possible solutions can be you can define unique Key with each Tile widget and compare them to remove. I don't think you need a separate class for this.

Comment: I updated my question, and I hope this makes clearer what I try to accomplish and how. @Iyio To my understanding I do call `setState()`, but I do not know why the ListView wont update.