# Flutter: Onpressed() function in a loop deletes last item irrespective of any item clicked

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello Flutter Expert,

Thank you very much for your help in learning Flutter & Dart. Now I got into another problem and need help.

I'm creating a list of widgets with a delete icon so I can remove items if required. When I click on remove, the last item gets removed irrespective of position. Seems like the index is updated insider onPressed() event. I'm not sure how can I fix it. can you pls check below and help me fix it? Thanks

```
    List<ParcelItem> parcelItems = List<ParcelItem>();

void addParcelItem(ParcelItem pi) {
parcelItems.add(pi);
}
void removeParcelItem(index){
parcelItems.removeAt(index);
}
Widget getItemList() {
List<Widget> widgetItems = List<Widget>();
int index = 0;
for (ParcelItem itm in parcelItems) {
  itm.id = index;
  Widget widgetItem =
  Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        flex: 40,
        child: TextFormField(
          initialValue: itm.name,
          //keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration:
            InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name '),
            onSaved: (value) {
              //print(value);
              name = value;
            }
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        flex: 25,
        child: TextFormField(
          initialValue: itm.description,
          //keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration:
            InputDecoration(hintText: 'Description '),
            onSaved: (value) {
              //print(value);
              description = value;
            }
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        flex: 5,
        child: TextFormField(
          initialValue: itm.quantity.toString(),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration:
            InputDecoration(hintText: 'Quantity '),
            onSaved: (value) {
              //print(value);
              quantity = int.parse(value);
            }
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        flex: 20,
        child: TextFormField(
          initialValue: itm.price.toString(),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration:
            InputDecoration(hintText: 'Price '),
            onSaved: (value) {
              //print(value);
              price = double.parse(value);
            }
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        flex: 10,
        child: Center(
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: (){
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: Text('Warning'),
                      content: Text('Are you sure you want to delete this record?'),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text('Yes'),
                          onPressed: (){ 
                            parcelItems.removeWhere((itm){ return (itm.id == parcelItems[index].id); });
                          },
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text('No'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          ),
        ),
      ),

    ],
  );
  widgetItems.add(widgetItem);

  index++;
}
if (widgetItems != null) {
  return Column(
    children: widgetItems,
  );
} else {
  return Text('Add some items', style: kInstructionText,);
}
}
```

Comment: You may have to set key for each list item. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390995/8660120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
List<ParcelItem> parcelItems = List<ParcelItem>();

void addParcelItem(ParcelItem pi) {
  parcelItems.add(pi);
}

void removeParcelItem(index) {
  parcelItems.removeAt(index);
}

Widget getItemList() {
  List<Widget> widgetItems = List<Widget>();
  int index = 0;
  for (ParcelItem itm in parcelItems) {
    itm.id = index;
    Widget widgetItem = Row(
      key: ObjectKey(itm), //TODO: Added Key Here
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          flex: 40,
          child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: itm.name,
              //keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name '),
              onSaved: (value) {
                //print(value);
                name = value;
              }),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 25,
          child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: itm.description,
              //keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Description '),
              onSaved: (value) {
                //print(value);
                description = value;
              }),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 5,
          child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: itm.quantity.toString(),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Quantity '),
              onSaved: (value) {
                //print(value);
                quantity = int.parse(value);
              }),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 20,
          child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: itm.price.toString(),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Price '),
              onSaved: (value) {
                //print(value);
                price = double.parse(value);
              }),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 10,
          child: Center(
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: Text('Warning'),
                      content:
                          Text('Are you sure you want to delete this record?'),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text('Yes'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState((){  //TODO: I assume this `getItemList` function is inside an State class 
                              parcelItems.remove(itm);  //TODO: doing this is will do the trick
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text('No'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    widgetItems.add(widgetItem);

    index++;
  }
  if (widgetItems != null) {
    return Column(
      children: widgetItems,
    );
  } else {
    return Text(
      'Add some items',
      style: kInstructionText,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can see you added "key: ObjectKey(itm)," only. can you pls add remove function codes as well so can test it? thanks

Comment: @NaveedAhmed I think adding `key` is enough. Is still last item only gets deleted?

Comment: I'm sorry but im new to flutter n dart. just have a look at the codes below and tell me if they are good?

onPressed: () {
                            parcelItems.removeWhere((itm) {
                              return (itm.id == parcelItems[index].id);
                            });
                          },

Comment: one more thing: im deleting item from list and inside setState() so we need to adjust this function so it binds right index inside the onpressed function?

Comment: @NaveedAhmed I updated the answer check it. The `onPressed` callback will know what `itm` its binded with. So you can just do `parcelItems.remove(itm)`

Comment: actually its working. was not using inside setState function. my bad. thank you very much for the help :-)